# Error setting up Vagrant with VirtualBox in PyCharm under OS X 10.10

Tags: python, macos, vagrant, virtualbox, pycharm

When setting up the remote interpreter and selecting Vagrant, I get the following error in PyCharm:

```
Can't Get Vagrant Settings: [0;31mThe provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine 'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The reason is shown bellow: Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed. Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the `VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environment variable.[0m
```

Now, from a terminal, everything works. I can do 'up' and ssh into the VM without issues. Ports are forwarded as well as local files. So the issue is only in PyCharm. I have installed Java 1.8

PATH is: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

which VBoxManage: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage and works in terminal.

Note that this is a fresh install of OS X done this morning. 
Vagrant version is 1.7.3, VirtualBox is 4.3.30 and PyCharm is 4.5.3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out, this problem is a known bug in PyCharm.

Until they fix it, you can get around the problem by launching PyCharm from a terminal window with the `charm` command.

[Vagrant 1.7.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.30 under Pycharm 4.5: Path issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16441)

Comment: This seems to also be true of their other IDE, like Rubymine and PhpStorm.

Comment: For those who did not do a fresh install of 4.5.3 version (comes from an upgrade), you should go to Tools>Create a Command-Line Launcher to create "charm" command and go for the workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this themaxx, and danigosa for the reminder on how to update the charm command. I have just spent 2 hours trying to figure this out, thought it was caused by an upgrade to vagrant 1.7.4 and virtualbox 5.

Answer (score 31):

Another workaround:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/bin/VBoxManage
```

Edit:

Since it all worked some time ago, one of the following has to be cause of this problem:

- either update of VirtualBox changed location of it's executable
- or update of PyCharm changed PATH settings / executable location expectation for the IDE

Whatever the cause is, the solution is to make sure VBoxManage is in location expected by PyCharm. I haven't make up this solution myself, just googled it, but because it is so nice and clean I decided to add it here.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit further why this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this was the simple fix (for me). I appreciate it.

Comment: your link is 404'd

Comment: @electrometro well, I guess that page has passed away or moved. I've removed that link.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solve the issue:

https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels/issues/184

I can call this command where my vagrant file was located:

```
vagrant plugin update vagrant-parallels
```

Also, this link added some help for python paths

[How to configure custom PYTHONPATH with VM and PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198319/how-to-configure-custom-pythonpath-with-vm-and-pycharm)