# VBoxManage is not found with Intellij PHP remote interpreter + vagrant

Tags: php, debugging, intellij-idea, vagrant, phpstorm

I want to add intellij php remote interpreter from vagrant and followed steps below.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Remote+PHP+Interpreters+in+PhpStorm#WorkingwithRemotePHPInterpretersinPhpStorm-DebuggingandRemotePHPInterpreters

But I got error

[image]

Error says VBoxManage command is not found in PATH, but I was able to find vboxmanage at my console.

```
 ~/Documents/sandbox/my-devenv/ [master*] which vboxmanage
/usr/local/bin/vboxmanage
 ~/Documents/sandbox/my-devenv/ [master*] vboxmanage -v
4.3.30r101610
```

I use vagrant 1.7.0 and Vboxmanage version is not too old.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem on OS X:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/bin/VBoxManage
```

Orginal source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32601098/687684

Comment: Really helped. Not sure why doesn't work with that as I got /usr/local/bin in my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem this week after I've upgraded Virtualbox to the latest 4.3.30. Downgrading back to 4.3.26 solved the issue

Comment: Thank you for your answering.
I got workaround using ssh to vagrant and solved the problem.

Comment: I used way "Adding a remote PHP interpreter over SSH"
instead of "Adding a remote PHP interpreter from Vagrant"

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Remote+PHP+Interpreters+in+PhpStorm#WorkingwithRemotePHPInterpretersinPhpStorm-1.RegisteringanewPHPinterpreter

Comment: @ShoOgihara afaik this way you won't be able to run phpunit tests correctly in VM