# Running spark-submit from pycharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pycharm

I am trying to figure out how to develop apache-spark program in PyCharm.
I have followed article in this [link](http://renien.github.io/blog/accessing-pyspark-pycharm/).
I define SPARK_HOME and add pyspark to Python path well. There is no error
in importing pyspark modules and autocomplete works fine.

However I get an error on defining SparkContext when I run the program in PyCharm.

```
Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python or R file)
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
...
...
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

I managed to run the program on terminal with submit-spark.
Do I need to change the configuration on PyCharm or Is there anyway to run
submit-spark instead of python in PyCharm?

Comment: this should help you https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine by terminal `submit-spark` you can [add a run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) that does that for you. Otherwise you can see some configuration in `Edit Run/Debug Configurations` window as well. [This post in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198319/how-to-configure-custom-pythonpath-with-vm-and-pycharm) can you get you there.