# Load environment variable from script in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I have a script which executes python unit tests. What this script does is firstly prepare the PYTHONPATH variable and then executes the python unit tests.

I now want to run my python tests in PyCharm, however I want to reuse the script which builds the environment variables. Is there a way to specify a script to prepare the env variables in run/debug configuration in PyCharm?

Comment: I dont know how to set python path using a script in PyCharm, but I think you may get some ideas from this from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198319/how-to-configure-custom-pythonpath-with-vm-and-pycharm

Comment: Doesn't "Edit Configurations" --> "Environment Variables" or "Before launch" cover your case?

Comment: in "Environment Variables" you'd have to specify each variable separately, that is you can not use a script. "Before launch" is running the tasks in separate process

Comment: Pretty old question. Has no one got an answer yet? I'm wondering this too...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `env-vars-in-path-vars` [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8063-environment-variables-in-path-variables) for IntelliJ IDEA family:

> An IntelliJ IDEA plugin to automatically add environment variables to
>   Path Variables.

For example, you can have a file `myproject.env` with next content:

```
SOME_VAR=SOME_VALUE
```

You can use this file from both your script and IDE, using the plugin and changing your environment variables would be reflected in both.