# I can't add libraries to python_path

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdal, qgis, osgeo

i'm trying to add new libraries to python_path, but I failed.

This is the new libraries path
[image: new libraries path]

and here my already added and recognized by external IDEs like pycharm libraries

[image: Path view]

so those new libraries I can work on, but only inside their apps.
I want to use them into PyCharm.

What should I do?

Comment: There's a difference between the system path, which controls where the OS looks for executables when you run them without a fully qualified path (e.g. when you run just "python", it'll look through the path for it. There's the Python path that's separate from that -- type `python -v` to see it being queried, or view `sys.path`.

Comment: okay, then 
what should i do to use modules inside that directory into PyCharm

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198319/how-to-configure-custom-pythonpath-with-vm-and-pycharm

Comment: use sys.path.append("path to library") in your main

Comment: i'm sorry, it didn't work
after excuting append() , still nothing when i try to import them Pycharm refuse to reconize modules

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem could come from the space in the "Program Files" folder so you can try using the short names path.

Open a dos command on the folder you want to use ([SHIFT]+ right mouse click => Command prompt here)

Type this command to get the dos form path ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051190/908929))

```
for %I in (.) do echo %~sI
```

Then use this path form as advised in the comments