# change django application directory in PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm

I have set up a Django project in PyCharm using `pipenv`.

I have used `pipenv` to create the virtual environment in my project directory.
Within the virtual environment directory, I have created `src` directory to place my Django project.

The directory structure is like

```
/ Project Directory
|- src
   |- django_app
   |- other_app
   |- manage.py
   |- db.sqlite3
|- Pipfile
|- Pipfile.lock
```

In `PyCharm` IDE, I have opened the `Project Directory` as a project.

When I use `Alt+Enter` to auto import modules from other apps. The import line is prefixed with `src.` like

```
from src.other_app.models import ModelName
```

Whereas It should be

```
from other_app.models import ModelName
```

**How can I reconfigure Django path in PyCharm to use `src` directory as root for Dango apps/modules?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pycharm when you open a project you are setting the `path` environment var in the folder that you opened, in this case `Project Directory`, but you can change `path` in pycharm doing something like is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992894/8196244). Only add `/src/` at the end of the path marked by `(added by user)`

Comment: @AnujTBE I'm glad that helped you, don't forget voteup