# I already install pygame. pycharm gave me not installed pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

i'm already installed python, pycharm, some packages.. and pygame installed on python i can see version at python shell, and i cant see pygame at pycharm.. cant inmport.. help!. 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UUKK.png)

Comment: Are you sure that you are using exactly the same python version in PyCharm?

Comment: I agree with the above comment. Seems like your system has multiple pythons, and the one pycharm uses is not the one you are running in the console. Either install pygame using pycharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html or fix the python version in pycharm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198319/how-to-configure-custom-pythonpath-with-vm-and-pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that probably you are starting your program with a different version of Python in Pycharm. 
You can see which is the current interpreter here:

```
Settings->Project->Project Interpreter
```

If the current interpreter is not the current one (means the one without pygame installed), you can change it.

At the top of the window, there is a list which contains all local interpreters. 
If you find it in the list select it, otherwise, in the right corner of the window, there is a settings icon; press it and press on Add local.

Once you have added it, you can use it in your game configuration.

That's it.