# uWSGI - ImportError: No module named google.oauth2.credentials

Tags: python-2.7, uwsgi

I am developing a Flask app that runs using uwsgi. I'm running into the following error `ImportError: No module named google.oauth2.credentials`.

When I run the Flask app using Flask's builtin dev server, the application runs without issues.

The problem seems to stem from how the `google-auth` module is installed. There's no `__init__.py` file in the `google` namespace folder in `site-packages`. The full path being `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google`.

I'm aware that python3.3 has implicit namespace packaging via [PEP-420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

What I'm confused about is how the implicit namespace packaging works in python2.7. Does the installation process via `pip` do something special?

I'm also confused about what is different when running python2.7 via uwsgi.

---

**Relevant versions**

- python 2.7.14
- pip 9.0.3
- uwsg 2.0.13
- google-auth 1.4.1

  - Installed via pip (not using virtualenv)
  - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python

---

I've also included the following barebones test to reproduce the error.

**test.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 0.0.0.0:5001
plugins-dir = /usr/lib/uwsgi/
plugins = python
protocol = uwsgi
pythonpath = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
callable = app
max-requests = 1000
master = True
lazy-apps = True
processes = 1
```

**test.py**

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
```

**working command**

```
python test.py
```

**failing command**

```
uwsgi --ini test.ini --wsgi-file test.py
```

**failing result**

When I run the above command, the program will fail due to the following ImportError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import google.oauth2.credentials
ImportError: No module named google.oauth2.credentials
```

---

**Current workaround**

My current workaround is to manually add an `__init__.py` file with the following (which is what is basically what is found in the google-auth repository, but for some reason is removed when installing via pip):

```
try:
    import pkg_resources
    pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    import pkgutil
    __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

**Workaround 2**

Another way I got the import working was by doing this:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

import google.oauth2.credentials
```

This seems to imply that uwsgi is not fully initialization python at least on initial start up.

I got the hint to try `site.addistedir` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209116/177646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a uWSGI configuration error on my part. Since I'm not using virtualenv, I needed to set `PYTHONHOME` to the correct value, which is `/usr/local` in my case. In the uwsgi configuration, this can be specified via the `home` parameter. Once this is set, then python seems to work normally.

Once the `PYTHONHOME` is correctly set, this allows the `google_auth-1.4.1-py3.6-nspkg.pth` file to be found.

This also explains why I had to always import `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in my `PYTHONPATH`. Once the `PYTHONHOME` is set, then I no longer needed to add site-packages to my `PYTHONPATH`.

Example:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 0.0.0.0:5001
plugins-dir = /usr/lib/uwsgi/
plugins = python
protocol = uwsgi
home = /usr/local
callable = app
max-requests = 1000
master = True
lazy-apps = True
processes = 1
```