# Python relative Imports with test folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there are probably thousands of posts like this and i nearly read them all and still i could not fix my issue.

I have the following project structure:

```
project
│
├── main.py           
├── module1
│   ├── __init__.py    
│   ├── b.py    
│   └── c.py
│
├── tests   
│   └── tests_module1.py
```

in tests_module1.py i want to import functions b.py and c.py to test their functionality. I already tried the following imports:

- from ..module1.b import *
- from module1.b import *
- from .. import b

I also tried adding **init**.py files to the project as well as the test folder with no succsess.
It only works when i move the test_module1.py into the project folder and import with :

- from module1.b import *

I am using Python 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15458607/7010554).
Python does not know the package structure if you run `python3 tests_module1.py` from within the `tests` directory.

Try the following `b.py`:

```
# module1/b.py

def hello():
    print("Hello world!")
```

Import it in `tests_module1.py`:

```
from module1 import b
b.hello()
```

Run it **from the `project` directory** with the `-m` (run as module) switch:

```
python3 -m tests.tests_module1
```

Comment: Thank you, running it from the project directory was the right hint. It is quiet obvious now that when I startet the test_module1.py inside the Test directory That the Interpreter doesn’t know anything about the module1.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `from .. import b` you must try

```
from ...module1 import *
```

Comment: This raises: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28492441)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Why do you say that? This may not be a _correct_ answer, but it’s certainly _an_ answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney - to me, the `try` means it is a suggestion that really otta be made in a _comment_.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: It’s okay to suggest that the OP “try” something ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256360/3025856)]. Such answers might merit downvoting, but not deletion. Same with code-only answers. Neither are considered _quality_ answers, but that’s what the downvote option is for. The _VLQ_ queue is for posts that make no effort to answer the question (i.e., “thanks”, “this didn’t work”, “I’m having this problem too”, or just a link) ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)).

Comment: @JeremyCaney - ah! thank you for the clarification. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at modifying the python search path: https://docs.python.org/3.9/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path

> **Modifying Python’s Search Path**
>
> When the Python interpreter executes an [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) statement, it searches for both Python code and extension modules along a search path. A default value for the path is configured into the Python binary when the interpreter is built. You can determine the path by importing the [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sys.html#module-sys) module and printing the value of `sys.path`...
>
> The expected convention for locally installed packages is to put them in the `…/site-packages/ directory`, but you may want to install Python modules into some arbitrary directory... There are several different ways to add the directory.
>
> The most convenient way is to add a path configuration file to a directory that’s already on Python’s path, usually to the `.../site-packages/` directory.  Path configuration files have an extension of `.pth`, and each line must contain a single path that will be appended to `sys.path`...
>
> <<snip several other options>>
>
> Finally, sys.path is just a regular Python list, so any Python application can modify it by adding or removing entries.

See also

- [Using .pth files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15208615/3744182)
- [Permanently adding a file path to sys.path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12257747/3744182)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28494010)

Comment: @codingCat Understood, thank you for the hint