# Error during import a module running tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I want to run unit tests using `unittest` module, this is the file organization of my project:

```
frac
├── frac.py
├── __init__.py
└── test
    └── run_tests.py
```

The code inside `run_tests.py` is:

```
import unittest
from frac import Fraction

class RunFractionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dunder_mul(self):
        self.assertEqual(Fraction(1, 2) * Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 4))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is, when i run `run_tests.py` with `python run_tests.py`, i get an error saying that the module `frac` was not found, this is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maurothecreator/Área de Trabalho/Projects/HighMath/frac/test/run_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from frac import Fraction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frac'
```

Am i importing this in the wrong way, if so, how can i fix this?

Comment: is the top `frac` directory on your pythonpath?  How do you run `frac.py` standalone?  by moving to the directory it's in?  Python puts the current directory in the pythonpath, so "things can work" even if you don't have your pythonpath set correctly to use python files from other locations.  like `frac/test`.

Comment: @JLPeyret i just run `python frac/test/run_tests.py` and then i get this error, i've used `echo $PYTHONPATH` and the return value is just an empty string

Comment: well, there you have it.  You need to set up your pythonpath correctly.  oh, and if you use the terminal using spaces in <Área de Trabalho> is going to bite you, a lot.

Comment: one way to set up python path is to make your workarea into an installable local pip, using the [`-e` pip flag](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-editable) .  Or you can use a .pth file.  or follow theeks suggestion, but do it in the appropriate .bashrc-type file.  the easiest, to me, is the [.pth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208615/using-pth-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following in the console before running `python run_tests.py`

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:<path_to_frac>"
```