# GLib.Error: Required gtk+ version 3.20, current version is 3.18 (7)

Tags: python, gtk, ubuntu-16.04, python-2.x

I have an old program written in Python2 i need to use, but it's not getting along with Ubuntu Xenial's dependencies.

I had to manually fetch these in order to get it to run:

```
libwebp6_0.6.1-2ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
libwebpdemux2_0.6.1-2ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
libwebpmux3_0.6.1-2ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
python-pil_5.1.0-1ubuntu0.7_amd64.deb
python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

When i run it, i get this:

```
myprog.py:12: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
```

followed by

```
GLib.Error: ... Required gtk+ version 3.20, current version is 3.18 (7)
```

Using `gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.20')` results in `ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available for version 3.20`.

I don't think there's GTK3 for Python2 on Xenial.

The newest `python-gtk2` i could find is the one installed, from [Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-gtk2). So i went and compiled [pybgobject](https://download.gnome.org/sources/pygobject/3.20/pygobject-3.20.1.tar.xz) 3.20 after installing a bunch of dependencies:

```
export GI_LIBS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib-2.0"
export GI_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0/include"
export PYCAIRO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/pycairo"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0"
./configure --prefix=${MY_BASE}/build --enable-static --enable-shared --with-python=python2
```

and tried to run it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_BASE}/build python2 myprog.py` but hit the same issue. I tried variations until `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_BASE}/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, same result.

Did i compile the wrong package? What am i missing?

These are the packages i have installed at the moment:

```
$ apt list --installed|grep python|grep -v python3

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

dh-python/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 2.20151103ubuntu1.2 all [installed]
libpython-dev/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpython-stdlib/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed]
libpython2.7/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13 amd64 [installed]
libpython2.7-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13 amd64 [installed]
libpython2.7-minimal/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13 amd64 [installed]
libpython2.7-stdlib/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13 amd64 [installed]
python/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed]
python-apt-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.11 all [installed]
python-cairo/xenial,now 1.8.8-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-cairo-dev/xenial,xenial,now 1.8.8-2 all [installed]
python-cheetah/xenial,now 2.4.4-3.fakesyncbuild1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-configparser/xenial,xenial,now 3.3.0r2-2 all [installed]
python-dev/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed]
python-dialog/xenial,now 3.3.0-2 amd64 [installed]
python-gi/xenial,now 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-gi-cairo/xenial,now 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python-gi-dev/xenial,now 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
python-gobject/xenial,xenial,now 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
python-gobject-2/xenial,now 2.28.6-12ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-gobject-2-dev/xenial,xenial,now 2.28.6-12ubuntu1 all [installed]
python-gobject-dev/xenial,xenial,now 3.20.0-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
python-gtk2/now 2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,local]
python-libvirt/xenial-updates,now 1.3.1-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-mako/xenial,xenial,now 1.0.3+ds1-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
python-markupsafe/xenial,now 0.23-2build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python-minimal/xenial-updates,now 2.7.12-1~16.04 amd64 [installed]
python-mysqldb/xenial,now 1.3.7-1build2 amd64 [installed]
python-pil/now 5.1.0-1ubuntu0.7 amd64 [installed,local]
python-pip/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.6 all [installed]
python-pip-whl/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.6 all [installed,automatic]
python-pkg-resources/xenial,xenial,now 20.7.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python-pygments/xenial,xenial,now 2.1+dfsg-1 all [installed,automatic]
python-sqlalchemy/xenial,xenial,now 1.0.11+ds1-1ubuntu2 all [installed]
python-talloc/xenial,now 2.1.5-2 amd64 [installed]
python-vm-builder/xenial,xenial,now 0.12.4+bzr494-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
python-yaml/xenial,now 3.11-3build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python2.7/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13 amd64 [installed]
python2.7-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python2.7-minimal/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13 amd64 [installed]
```

Also added these:

```
libglade2-0_2.6.4-2_amd64.deb
python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: You might just want to update the program to Python 3 (however, I don't know how feasible that is, given that I don't know the size of your program). That way, you don't have to install old dependencies for an old version of a language that isn't even maintained anymore.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin not a rabbit hole i want to get into, really. I shouldn't be using Ubuntu 16.04 to begin with...

Comment: It looks to me like, based on old SO [tag:pygtk] questions, that maybe Python 2 uses PyGtk, not Gtk2. Have you tried using that? Again, I strongly suggest you upgrade to Python 3. It may be easier. It certainly will be better in the long run, if you wish to keep using this program (sorry for the slow response, Firefox forced me to update and I had to rewrite the comment).

Comment: It has `import gi`, so i assume it uses [PyGObject](https://www.gtk.org/docs/language-bindings/python/). I've installed the [latest version](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#windows-getting-started) through msys and [sys.path.append](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209116/1831722)ed it to the main script.

Comment: (previous comment was about a windows vm, i got the app to start on a xenial vm)

Answer (score 0):

I've since got it to work on Xenial, but the app doesn't work correctly: the File, Edit, ... menu options don't work, for instance.

From my ever-growing notes, i got it to work by compiling [pygobject-3.20.1.tar.xz](https://download.gnome.org/sources/pygobject/3.20/pygobject-3.20.1.tar.xz), with

```
export GI_LIBS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib-2.0"
export GI_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0/include"
export PYCAIRO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/pycairo"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0"
./configure --prefix=${PWD}/build/linux/x86_64 --enable-static --enable-shared --with-python=python2
```

but i'm not sure that's the path i followed and i was in a temporary directory.

Anyway, now i'm having the same issue in an windows vm.