# upgrading GTK from 3.18 to 3.20 in msys for python 2

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, glade, msys

I managed to get an old Python 2 app [running on Xenial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130062/glib-error-gtk-builder-error-quark-main-window-glade51-required-gtk-version), but the menus aren't working and i've since borked *that* particular installation (can be recovered i guess). I was told this "used to work in a windows vm" so am having a go at it.

I already had msys, added some [gtk](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#windows-getting-started) dependencies and spent the better part of two days tracking down and installing old packages to satisfy more dependencies, using `pip`, wheels, [pypi](https://pypi.org/) and, more frequently than not, scavenging old versions that still supported Python 2 in git repos and then `setup.py install` them, sometimes with the help of [Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291955/1831722).

Now i hit the same error i once had in Xenial: `GLib.Error: ... Required gtk+ version 3.20, current version is 3.18 (7)`, only then i *think* solved it by compiling pygobject but i don't recall it.

I've installed the `GTK` and `Gdk` components of [PyGObject for windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/latest/download) onto my `/c/Python27/` <del>msys</del> installation, and i have these msys packages installed (relevant to this):

```
$ pacman -Ss glade
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-glade 3.38.2-1
    User interface builder for GTK+ and GNOME (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-glade-gtk2 3.8.6-4
    User interface builder for GTK+ and GNOME (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-libglade 2.6.4-6
    Allows you to load glade interface files in a program at runtime (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-glade 3.38.2-1 [installed]
    User interface builder for GTK+ and GNOME (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-glade-gtk2 3.8.6-4 [installed]
    User interface builder for GTK+ and GNOME (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-libglade 2.6.4-6 [installed]
    Allows you to load glade interface files in a program at runtime (mingw-w64)
ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-glade 3.38.2-1
    User interface builder for GTK+ and GNOME (mingw-w64)
ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-glade-gtk2 3.8.6-4
    User interface builder for GTK+ and GNOME (mingw-w64)
ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libglade 2.6.4-6
    Allows you to load glade interface files in a program at runtime (mingw-w64)
clang64/mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-glade 3.38.2-1
    User interface builder for GTK+ and GNOME (mingw-w64)
clang64/mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-glade-gtk2 3.8.6-4
    User interface builder for GTK+ and GNOME (mingw-w64)
clang64/mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-libglade 2.6.4-6
    Allows you to load glade interface files in a program at runtime (mingw-w64)
```

```
$ pacman -Ss gtk | grep ^mingw64
...
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-glade 3.38.2-1 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-glade-gtk2 3.8.6-4 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2 2.70.4-1 [installed]
...
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk-engines 2.21.0-4
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk-update-icon-cache 3.24.31+76+g3dc44becf0-1 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk2 2.24.33-4 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 3.24.31+76+g3dc44becf0-1 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4 4.6.1-1
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkada 3.8.2-2
...
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-gobject 3.40.1-2 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-pygtk 2.24.0-8 [installed]
...
```

```
$ pacman -Ss python | grep ^mingw64| grep installed
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python 3.9.10-2 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-cairo 1.20.1-2 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-gobject 3.40.1-2 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pillow 9.0.1-1 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python2 2.7.18-4 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-cairo 1.18.2-3 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-gobject2 2.28.7-3 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-pygtk 2.24.0-8 [installed]
```

My `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\easy-install.pth` has nothing GTK-related:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./sqlalchemy-1.4.31-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
./sqlalchemy-1.4.31dev-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
./configparser-0.0.0-py2.7.egg
./contextlib2-0.6.0-py2.7.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

I've [appended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209116/1831722) `/mingw64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/` to my app's `sys.path`:

```
sys.path.append('/mingw64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0')
sys.path.append('/mingw64/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/c/Python27/lib/site-packages')
```

This is because i'm using `/c/Python27/python.exe` and its `lib/site-packages` is where all the fun is at, but i get the same result with `/mingw64/bin/python2.7.exe`.

Python's not my *forte* nor will i upgrade this app to Python 3. How do i go about upgrading gtk?

---

*Edit1*

According to GTK's [website](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/#using-gtk-from-msys2-packages) i should use mysys, which i have, and the version should suffice:

```
$ pacman -Qi mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
Name            : mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
Version         : 3.24.31+76+g3dc44becf0-1
```

(I even ended up compiling the [latest mysys GTK3](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-gtk3) which caused only a minor version bump.)

My script loads glade data:

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("xmlfile")
```

The file has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
```

and thus it fails, because it's fetching GTK from [PyGObject for windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/) instead of the msys env.

`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gnome\libgtk-3-0.dll` is 3.18.9
`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll` is 3.24.31

[PyGobject on msys](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-pygobject) seems to be fairily up-to-date (no GTK changes from my installed 3.40.1 to 3.42.0), but Python2 support has apparently been dropped in 3.38.0.

I can't just replace the .dll in `gnome\` and can't seem to get python to use the one in `bin\` atm.

---

Recompiling [mingw-w64-pygobject2](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-gobject2?repo=mingw64) didn't quite help: the last version to support Python 2 is [3.36.0](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id6) but using msys to build anything other than that version, ahead or before, yileds patching errors.